# Graph of the function $\frac{(x-1)(x-4)}{(x-2)(x-3)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

We are given the function 
$$\frac{(x-1)(x-4)}{(x-2)(x-3)}$$ 
and we have to draw graph of this.

We know its domain will be all real numbers except $x=2$ and $x=3$; also, it has a local minimum at $x=\frac52$.

But now how to proceed?

Answer (score 8):

We can find out many more factoids about the graph: There is a zero at $x=1$ and one at $x=4$, both with a change of sign, the poles at $x=2$, $x=3$ are also with change of sign. We have a horizontal asymptote $y=1$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. Additionally, the graph is in fact symmetric to $x=\frac52$. These should be enough guiding hints to allow you making a good enough sketch of the graph:

Coming from negative infinity the graph is close to the line $y=1$ and falls down to intersect the $x$ axis at $x=1$ and then tend to $-\infty$ as $x\to 2^-$; to the right of $x=2$, the graph comes down again from $+\infty$, passes through the minimum at $x=\frac52$ 8and $y=9$, as you may compute) just do go up to $+\infty$ again as we approach $3$ from the left; to the right of $3$ the graph comes up again from $-\infty$, crosses the $x$ axis at $x=4$ and huddles against the line $y=1$ again.

Comment: Shouldn't the poles be at $x=2, x=3$?

Comment: How can we say it is symmetric to x=5/2

Comment: @zz20s Thanks, edited

Comment: @user101522 because we can verify that $f(5-x)=f(x)$. Anyway, this is just a "bonus" property

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and what more can we conclude from it

Comment: Value at local minimum is 9, and that should be sufficient with all other remarks in this answer

Comment: @user101522 Not much (except that we could have found the local extremum without computing derivatives), but you may want to make sure that your sketch does look somewhat symmetric ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No problem.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  the graph between x=2,3 will be concave or convex or a straight line

Comment: The sign of the first derivative will also give you the intervals on which the function is increasing/decreasing, although in this case it is "obvious" from the other bits of information.

Comment: @DemK. I got the graph between x =2,3 but what about other part of graph